# Как сделать правильную выборку с двух таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать?

Есть база `data1` с таблицей `wp_users` и строкой `user_login`.
Есть база `data2` с таблицей `money` и строкой `username` и `balance`.
Поля `user_login` и `username` хоть и в разных таблицах, но они одинаковые.

Как cделать выборку, чтобы `user_login` выбрал `username` и посмотрел какое значение в строке `balance` и вывел его в переменную?
Есть наброски, которые не работают.

Comment: А что значит user_login выбрал username. Каковы условия выборки из первой таблицы ? А вообще select balance from data1.wp_users a, data2.money b where a.user_login=b.username. Но вы же наверно что то другое на самом деле хотите

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться следующим запросом

```
SELECT
  u.user_login AS user,
  m.balance AS balance
FROM
  data1.wp_users AS u
LEFT JOIN
  data2.money AS m
ON
  u.user_login = m.username
```